# Spark DataFrame Aggregation based on two or more Columns

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to write a UDAF for some customized aggregation based on more than one column. A simple example would be a dataframe with two columns, c1 and c2. For each row, I take the max of c1 and c2 (let's call it cmax), then I take the sum of cmax.

When I call df.agg(), it does not look like I can pass two or more columns to any aggregation method including UDAF. 1st question, is it true?

For this simple example, I could create another column called cmax, and do the aggregation on cmax. But in reality, I would need to do aggregation based on N combinations of columns and the results would be a collection of size N. I would want to loop the combinations within the update method in my UDAF. Therefore it would require N intermediate columns, which does not seem to be a clean solution to me. 2nd question, I wonder if creating intermediate columns is the way to do it, or if there is a better solution.

I noticed in RDD, the problem is much easier. I can pass the entire record to my aggregation function and I have access to all the data fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use as many columns in a UDAF as the signature of it's `apply` function accepts multiple `Columns` (from it's source code).

```scala
 def apply(exprs: Column*): Column
```

You just have to make sure that the `inputSchema` returns a `StructType` reflecting the columns that you want to consume as your UDAF input.

For the case of columns `c1` and `c2` your UDAF has to implement a `inputSchema` with the following schema:

```scala
def inputSchema: StructType = StructType(Array(StructField("c1", DoubleType), StructField("c2", DoubleType)))
```

However if you want a more general solution, you can always initialize the custom UDAF with arguments that allows returning the right `inputSchema`. See the example below that allows defining an arbitrary `StructType` at construction time (**Note** that we don't verify that `StructType` is of `DoubleType`).

```scala
class MyMaxUDAF(schema: StructType) extends UserDefinedAggregateFunction {

  def inputSchema: StructType = this.schema

  def bufferSchema: StructType = StructType(Array(StructField("maxSum", DoubleType)))

  def dataType: DataType = DoubleType

  def deterministic: Boolean = true

  def initialize(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer): Unit = buffer(0) = 0.0

  def update(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer, input: Row): Unit = {
buffer(0) = buffer.getDouble(0) + Array.range(0, input.length).map(input.getDouble).max
  }

  def merge(buffer1: MutableAggregationBuffer, buffer2: Row): Unit = buffer2 match {
    case Row(buffer2Sum: Double) => buffer1(0) = buffer1.getDouble(0) + buffer2Sum
  }

  def evaluate(buffer: Row): Double = buffer match {
    case Row(totalSum: Double) => totalSum
  }

}
```

Your DataFrame containing values and a key for aggregation.

```scala
val df = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
  Entry(0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0), Entry(0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0), Entry(1, 6.0, 2.0, 2)
))
df.show


+-------+---+---+---+
|groupMe| c1| c2| c3|
+-------+---+---+---+
|      0|1.0|2.0|3.0|
|      0|3.0|1.0|2.0|
|      1|6.0|2.0|2.0|
+-------+---+---+---+
```

And using the UDAF we expect the sum of max being 6.0 and 6.0

```scala
val fields = Array("c1", "c2", "c3")
val struct = StructType(fields.map(StructField(_, DoubleType)))
val myMaxUDAF: MyMaxUDAF = new MyMaxUDAF(struct)
df.groupBy("groupMe").agg(myMaxUDAF(fields.map(df(_)):_*)).show


+-------+---------------------+
|groupMe|mymaxudaf(c1, c2, c3)|
+-------+---------------------+
|      0|                  6.0|
|      1|                  6.0|
+-------+---------------------+
```

There is a nice tutorial on UDAF. Unfortunately they don't cover multiple arguments.

https://ragrawal.wordpress.com/2015/11/03/spark-custom-udaf-example/

Comment: Not sure about the 22 argument limit. Where did you find that?

Comment: Scala has the max 22 arguments per function. Not sure, but the signature of the UDAF reads each column as single argument, and not a list of columns. Need to verify, but now I'm at the phone.